# Auto select file in Solution Explorer from its open tab

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Normally, many files in [Visual Studio 2010](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2010) are opened in many tabs, while massively working on a project. Many times, I find myself right-clicking on a tab title and searching for `Show/Select/Scroll-to this file in Solution Explorer`, and I can't find it.

Is there a way to automatically select an opened file in Solution Explorer?

Comment: Yeah, I keep almost turning back on the "Track Active Item in Solution Explorer", then I remember how much I disliked that, because I'd lose track of the section of the project I was working on.  However, I also often want to *on-demand* "focus-to" the document I'm editing, to see all the items in nearby namespaces. For example, maybe I've just gone 5 references deep in a project I don't know well, using F12 (Go to definition). I don't want 5 trees open so I can't get back to my focal project, but I now want to inspect the third-party library for a moment.

Answer (score 437, accepted):

Another option is to bind 'View.TrackActivityInSolutionExplorer' to a keyboard short-cut, which is the same as 'Tools-->Options-->Projects and Solutions-->Track Active Item in Solution Explorer'

If you activate the short-cut twice the file is selected in the solution explorer, and the tracking is disabled again.

**Visual Studio 2013+**

There is now a feature built in to the VS2013 solution explorer called Sync with Active Document. The icon is two arrows in the solution explorer, and has the hotkey <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd> to show the current document in the solution explorer. Does not enable the automatic setting mentioned above, and only happens once.

Comment: Keyboard binding is done in Tools/Options.../Environment/Keyboard -- I went with binding Ctrl+Alt+] (close square bracket).

Comment: 'Tools-->Options-->Projects and Solutions-->Track Active Item in Solution Explorer' still works in Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition.

Comment: 'Tools-->Options-->Projects and Solutions-->Track Active Item in Solution Explorer' still works in Visual Studio 2019

Comment: Why is this not enabled by default?

Comment: 'Tools-->Options-->Projects and Solutions-->Track Active Item in Solution Explorer' still works in Visual Studio 2022

Comment: At least from VS17, `Ctrl`+`[`, `S`, which is bound to a command .SolutionExplorer.SyncWithActiveDocument, is not available. Is there any alternative way?

Answer (score 245):

I don't know if you can do it on-demand, but you can enable the option "Track Active Item in Solution Explorer" (Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->General) which will always select the active tab item in the solution explorer.

Comment: More precisely: Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> General ->

Answer (score 43):

If you're using the [ReSharper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReSharper) plugin, you can do that using the <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> shortcut or navigate via menu as shown.

[image]

Answer (score 33):

This isn't exactly what you're looking for, but it would automatically select the "active" file in the Solution Explorer:

Tools-->Options-->Projects and Solutions-->Track Active Item in Solution Explorer.

Answer (score 17):

simply Tools--> Options--> Projects and Solutions--> Track Active Item in Solution Explorer

Comment: hope it help any one need it

Answer (score 10):

In visual studio 2022

Similar to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8473574/13275637

You need to tick **Track Active Item in solution Explorer**

[image]

Answer (score 9):

The best option now is to install the Microsoft Visual Studio add on called *[Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef)*.

With this comes "Solution Navigator" (alternative to Solution Explorer, with a lot of benefits) - which then you can use to filter the files to only show "Open". You can even filter files to show "Edited" and "Unsaved".

Answer (score 8):

In VS 2019  select **Tools > Options**  and then tick "**Track Active Item in Solution Explorer**"
[image]

Answer (score 7):

It's in VS2012 - Specifically the 2-Arrow icon at the top of the solution explorer (Left/Right arrows, one above the other). This automatically jumps to the current file.

This icon is only visible if you've got `Track Active Item in Solution Explorer` disabled.

Answer (score 5):

In Visual Studio 2012, the same can be done using the "Sync With Active Document" option in Solution Explorer

Answer (score 3):

The Tab Studio plugin adds "select in solution explorer" to the right click menu on tabs.

Comment: i knew i saw it somewhere... thanks for pointing it out it was in tabstudio (which i had installed)

Answer (score 2):

There's a very nice extension to VS2010, which does exactly this: [Solution Explorer Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ef4ac3e9-d056-4383-8ca2-11721bd879b4).

This extension adds a button which selects the current file in the solution explorer, as well as convenient buttons for collapsing and expanding projects.

Answer (score 2):

[That's the screenshot of the answer for your question.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sH9MA.png)

Answer (score 1):

I've put in a [feature request](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2255650-remove-default-feature-for-following-current-docum) for this very feature. Although I know this isn't an answer in itself it is a step in the direction of being able to get this feature implemented. Any votes it it may help to get Microsoft's attention.

As far as I'm aware of though there is no way to do this other than possibly writing a macro or creating your own add-in/extension to Visual Studio.